# Markov property and memoryless property

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, markov-process

Let X be N~(0,1).
Show that:
$$
\mathcal{P} (X > t + \frac{a}{t} | X>t) \underbrace{\longmapsto}_{t \longmapsto \infty} e^{-a} 
$$

I used firstly the memoryless property and then the markov inequality:
$$
\mathcal{P} (X > t + \frac{a}{t} | X>t) = P(X > \frac{a}{t})
$$
by Markov and applying the exponential function since increasing and continuos:
$$
\mathcal{P}(e^X > e^{\frac{a}{t}}) \leq \frac{E(e^x)}{e^{\frac{a}{t}}} = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\frac{a}{t}}}
$$

Thus, it's not the result that I needed when t goes to infinity. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: I fail to see how the memoryless property applies here; $X$ is given to be normally distributed, and it is well-known that the exponential distribution is the only absolutely continuous probability distribution for which the memoryless property applies...

Comment: Ok well, so I completely missed the exercise. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, it suffices to verify the assertion by definition. Let $\Phi(x)$ be the c.d.f. of standard normal distribution.
$$
\begin{align}
P(X > t + \frac at | X > t) &= \frac{P(X > t + \frac at, X > t)}{P(X > t)} \\
&=\frac{P(X > t + \frac at)}{P(X > t)} \\
&= \frac{1 - \Phi(t + a/t)  }{1 - \Phi(t)} \quad\text{ apply L'Hôpital's rule}\\
&\to \frac{-\Phi^\prime(t+a/t)(1 -a/t^2)}{-\Phi^\prime(t)} \\
&\to \frac{e^{-\frac12(t+a/t)^2}}{e^{-\frac12t^2}} \\
&\to e^{-a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If $\Phi$ denotes the CDF then the third line should be $\frac{1-\Phi(t+a/t)}{1-\Phi(t)}$.

Comment: I was wondering, why do you apply de l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @Ricter, the limitation is $\frac00$ form.